# Add UIView above UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I currently add UIView above UITableView. it works, but look like empty UITableViewCell's appear below like this:

[image]

There is code of my second view (.m file):

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"Calld");
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self addLabel];
    return self;
}

-(void)addLabel{

    UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 220, 304, 128)];
    fromLabel.text = @"( Щелкните на экран, чтобы добавить задачи )";

    fromLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    fromLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines; // or UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters, or UIBaselineAdjustmentNone
    fromLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    fromLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
    fromLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
    fromLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    fromLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    fromLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    fromLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [self addSubview:fromLabel];
}
```

And main view:

```
 InitialView *initView = [[InitialView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.view addSubview:initView];
```

How to remove that empty rows, and then delete view and show table again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can increase fromLabel height or set InitialView background color to hide those empty rows.
If you want to remove those put this code in your controller where you have table view.

```
yourTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

and to remove your view so your tableview is visible again use.

```
[initView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the empty rows or view.
Just make the **tableview Hidden** till the data is not loaded - in viewWillLoad

after tableview is populated and you are **reloading tableview,** Make **tableview.hidden = NO;**

by default, empty rows will show, until unless You have given the **separator line color** of tableview to be clearcolor.